# Get url for current page, but with a different format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails 2. I want a link to the current page (whatever it is) that keeps all of the params the same but changes the format to 'csv'.  (setting the format can be done by having format=csv in the params or by putting .csv at the end of the path).  Eg

```
posts/1
=> posts/1.csv OR posts/1?format=csv
posts?name=jim 
=> posts.csv?name=jim OR posts?name=jim&format=csv
```

I tried this as a hacky attempt

`request.url+"&format=csv"`

and that works fine if there are params in the current url (case 2 above) but breaks if there aren't (case 1).  I could come up with more hacky stuff along these lines, eg testing if the request has params, but i'm thinking there must be a nicer way.

cheers, max

EDIT - btw, it's not guaranteed that the current page could have a named route associated with it, in case that's relevant: we could have got there via the generic "/:controller/:action/:id" route.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "This page in CSV", {:format => :csv } %>
<%= link_to "This page in PDF", {:format => :pdf } %>
<%= link_to "This page in JPEG", {:format => :jpeg } %>
```

**EDIT**

Add helper

```
def current_url(new_params)
  url_for :params => params.merge(new_params)
end
```

then use this

```
<%= link_to "This page in CSV", current_url(:format => :csv ) %>
```

**EDIT 2**

Or improve your hack:

```
def current_url(new_params)
  params.merge!(new_params)
  string = params.map{ |k,v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join("&")
  request.uri.split("?")[0] + "?" + string
end
```

**EDIT**

IMPORTANT! @floor - your approach above has a serious problem - it directly modifies params, so if you've got anything after a call to this method which uses params (such as will_paginate links for example) then that will get the modified version which you used to build your link. I changed it to call .dup on params and then modify the duplicated object rather than modifying params directly. – @Max Williams

Comment: doh, actually, that's no good :(  It changes "/music_service_admin/schools" to "/music_service_admin/schools/index.csv".  While index is the right action, that url doesn't work because the route interpreter thinks that "index" is an id and goes to the show action.

Comment: EDIT 1 suffers from the same problem, ie /resources => /resources/index.csv

Comment: IMPORTANT!  @floor - your approach above has a serious problem - it directly modifies params, so if you've got anything after a call to this method which uses params (such as will_paginate links for example) then that will get the modified version which you used to build your link.  I changed it to call .dup on params and then modify the duplicated object rather than modifying params directly.

Comment: This works better using `request.query_parameters` rather than `params` to obtain the parameters, because `params` includes the `controller` and `page` parameters too..

Comment: This can be insecure as `params` are user input. I believe that on Rails 5 this actually generates an error such as "Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters!"

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
link_to "text of link", your_controller_path(format:'csv',params: request.query_parameters)
```

Comment: While this code sample may possible answer the question, as it is now it is not very helpful. Please add some explanation to this answer.

Answer (score -1):

@floor's answer was great, I found it very useful.

Although the method can be improved by using the to_params method rather than contructing your own, like so:

```
def current_url(new_params)
  params.merge!(new_params)
  "#{request.uri}#{params.to_params}"
end
```