# Rails forms: How to append request params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I got a list page and I filter items via links with get params (I can choose many links so query would be like `"?param1=value1&param2=value2"`). But also I have to filter it by text field, so I made a form:

```
<form>
  <%= text_field_tag :zip, params[:zip] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'OK', :name => nil %>
</form>
```

But when I submit it, text field param replaces existing query params. So, how to make text field value add to query, not to replace it?

Answer (score 6):

Since I was just dealing with this problem in Rails 4 I thought I'd share my solution.
My page gets loaded with a sport_id parameter, and when the user specifies a sort-order I wanted it to submit a GET request for page.url/event?sport_id=1&sortby=viewers but it wouldn't preserve the sport_id parameter until I added a hidden field tag in the form like so:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :sport_id, params[:sport_id] %>
```

This solution does submit an empty sport_id parameter if that parameter was not in the original request, but that is easily prevented by encapsulating the hidden field in an <% if params[:sport_id].present? %> condition.

Answer (score 2):

### Use `hidden_field_tag`.

Inside of your form, just set `hidden_field_tags` for the existing `GET` params, like so:

```
<% request.query_parameters.collect do |key, value| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag key, value %>
<% end %>
```

This will ensure that your existing params persist.

Comment: will this work work for nested params ?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3?

```
<%= form_tag your_path(params.except(:controller, :action)), :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :zip, params[:zip] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'OK', :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried it too: not working. This way query looks like:
.action=index&controller=controllername&param1=value?method=get

Comment: typo: a bracket should be before :mathod

Comment: So that it behaves like in the beginning: replaces existing params :(

Comment: it shouldn't. What do you use as `your_path` ?

Comment: I use this:
match '/path', :controller => :name, :action => 'index', :as => :path

Comment: <%= form_tag path_path(params.except([:controller, :action])), :method => :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :zip, params[:zip] %>
        <%= submit_tag 'OK', :name => nil %>
      <% end %>

Comment: `<%= form_tag your_path(params.except(:controller, :action)), :method => :get do %>` remove square brackets

Comment: checkout this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913525/get-url-for-current-page-but-with-a-different-format/5913552#5913552