# Converting URL to JSON version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

On all the pages of my app, I want a link to the JSON version of current page. Any neat tricks to do this? Where it got complicated was when additional '&' parameters were included in the URL.

So the urls would be transposed as:

```
'/users' => '/users.json'

'/users?page=1&per_page=5' => '/users.json?page=1&per_page=5'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Attribution for this answer from [Get url for current page, but with a different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913525/get-url-for-current-page-but-with-a-different-format), with modifications:

Helper:

```
def current_url(new_params)
 url_for params.merge(new_params)
end
```

Link:

```
<%= link_to "JSON of this page", current_url(:format=>:json)
```

Comment: as said in the question you quote, you should duplicate params before using them. Anyway, feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: What was different was the requirement for "url_for :params => params.merge(new_params)", instead of just "url_for params.merge(new_params)".

Answer (score 13):

try this :

```
polymorphic_path( @user, :format => :json )
```

(as seen in this [API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes))

alternatively :

```
user_path( :id => @user.id, :format => :json )
```

Comment: I need the link to the JSON version on every page, so the link would be different for that page's path and I may have one, or many associated objects. Is there a way to just git the named path of the current page and append the :format => :json?

Comment: i found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913525/get-url-for-current-page-but-with-a-different-format), should help you

Comment: also, when i need to set the locale but to keep the current page, i use `url_for( :locale => :en )` for example. It works with `:locale`, so maybe it will work with `:format`

Comment: thanks. The link you posted didn't totally work with Rails 3.1, but I was able to figure it out. Edited above.